# how to add new data each cycle and how to describe 'cycle' in matlab is better

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to apply the dynamic rough K-means algorithm described in the paper：
A Dynamic Approach to Rough Clustering:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-88425-5_39

As the pic shows,I want to know how to add new data each cycle and how to describe 'cycle' in matlab is better.[image]
I can only come up with the way of describing 'for' loop as the cycles and announce a newData array which stored the new data in advance to add data
in each cycle(loop) like below:

```
newData = [cycle1,cycle2,cycle3,...cyclec];
for i = 1:c
    %it is a new cycle
    newdata = newData[i];
    %classify new data...
    %check for structural changes..
    %updata parameters and data...
end
```

Is there any way more better?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about *better*, but there are other ways. Depending on how your data arrives you might consider some form of processing inside a while loop. Just to give you an idea of how this might work.

```
% Some initializatian
init();

while ~isEmpty()
    %it is a new cycle
    newData = getData()
    %classify new data...
    %check for structural changes..
    %updata parameters and data...
end

function x = getData()
    global counter;
    data = [1, 2, 3];
    x = data(counter);    
    counter = counter + 1;
end

function empty = isEmpty()
    global counter;
    empty = counter > 3;
end

function init()
    global counter;
    counter = 1;
end
```

This is not meant to be your implementation. It is meant to give you an idea how this might look an a high level. In `getData` you would get the next data point from whatever source you might have. And instead of having a global counter you could consider putting your behavior and data together into an object.